# Testing lock-screen controls for music app in Emulator; how to lock screen without shutting down app?

Tags: android, android-emulator, lockscreen

I'm working on a music player app, that shows the media controls on the lockscreen in Android api 19 and 22.

In order to test that capability, I'm running it in the emulator.

I can start a song playing, but when I press the power button (in the right panel of the emulator), the screen goes dark, the song keeps playing for a short time, then stops. When I press the power button again, the lock screen shows, with the controls, but pressing the controls does not do anything. Unlocking the screen shows the app, but it can't resume playing the song.

On a real phone, turning the screen off has the expected effect; the song keeps playing, the lock screen controls work, and the app works after the screen is turned back on and unlocked.

How do I make the emulator act like a real phone?